# How to point Nginx docker container to the correct container for my web app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-ecs

I am setting up my Ruby on Rails application on AWS ECS and would like to redirect my website, example.com, to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). I am running into an issue with redirecting my Nginx upstream server to my Rails app. Everything seems to work fine locally. My Docker container crashes with the following error message:

```
[emerg] 8#8: host not found in upstream "web:3000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:3
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "web:3000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:3
```

Here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      args:
        DEPLOY_ENV_ARG: ${DEPLOY_ENV:-development}
        SERVER_ENV_ARG: ${SERVER_ENV:-development}
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

  nginx:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.nginx
    links:
      - web
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Dockerfile.nginx

```
FROM nginx:1.23-alpine

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
```

nginx.conf

```
upstream rails_app {
  server web:3000;
}

server {
  server_name example.com;

  # Redirect all http://example.com requests to http://www.example.com
  return 301 $scheme://www.$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  # server_name www.example.com;
  server_name xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com; # My ALB address hostname

  # Specify the public application root
  root   /example/public;

  # Specify where Nginx should write its logs
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  # Deny requests for files that should never be accessed such as .rb or .log files
  location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
  }

  location ~* ^.+\.(rb|log)$ {
    deny all;
  }

  # Serve static (compiled) assets directly
  location ~ ^/(assets|images|javascripts|stylesheets|swfs|system)/   {
    try_files $uri @rails;
    access_log off;
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
  }

  # Send non-static file requests to the app server
  location / {
    try_files $uri @rails;
  }

  # Reverse proxy redirecting the request to the rails app, port 3000.
  location @rails {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://rails_app;
    proxy_read_timeout 900;
  }
}
```

If it's helpful, here's the output of `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                                             COMMAND
  CREATED          STATUS                  PORTS                                       NAMES
4634eafd0ac1   xxxxxxxxxx.xxx.xxx.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/example_web_production:latest      "./docker/web-entryp…"   3 seconds ago    Up 2 seconds            0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, :::3000->3000/tcp   ecs-example_web_production-10-web-aad0d39b88a584e02800
3385ac3e9bcd   amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest                                                    "/agent"
  37 hours ago     Up 37 hours (healthy)                                               ecs-agent
```

How can I get the Nginx config to recognize the `web` container running on the same instance?

Comment: try to add `depends_on`. may be the `web` container still doesn't exist when `nginx` starts

Comment: Proxy_pass does not see rails_app.

Comment: @MikiBelavista Can you elaborate please? All the examples I found show a setup like this, using an upstream in the proxy_pass.

Comment: @Alexander try to inspect both containers. You can also put them on the same bridge network.

Comment: @YuriG @MikiBelavista thank you, but those solutions unfortunately didn't work. It seems that the container name in AWS is dynamically set, so `web` doesn't seem to exist. Is there a way to dynamically retrieve the docker container name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! Nginx could not find the `web` container because the links between the `nginx` and `web` containers were not set in the AWS ECS task definition. This is what my task definition looked like before:

```
{
  ...
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "nginx",
      "image": "xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/nginx:latest",
      "cpu": 0,
      "links": [],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 80,
          "hostPort": 0,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ],
      "essential": true,
      ...
    },
    {
      "name": "web",
      "image": "xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/web:latest",
      "cpu": 0,
      "links": [],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 3000,
          "hostPort": 3000,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ],
      "essential": true,
      ...
    }
  ]

  ...
}
```

Now it looks like the following (note the `links`):

```
{
  ...
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "nginx",
      "image": "xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/nginx:latest",
      "cpu": 0,
      "links": [
        "web"
      ],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 80,
          "hostPort": 0,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ],
      "essential": true,
      ...
    },
    {
      "name": "web",
      "image": "xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/web:latest",
      "cpu": 0,
      "links": [],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 3000,
          "hostPort": 3000,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ],
      "essential": true,
      ...
    }
  ]

  ...
}
```

I had to use the old ECS console in order to add the `web` container as link; the new console doesn't have that option yet. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56537302/2430657) for a screenshot.